# Dreamweaver like feature in apatana

Tags: aptana

I am a web developer and like to try my hands on any kind of text editors i feel relevant, mostly i am on windows . Recently heard about this cool text editor which is "almost" similar in features to Dreamweaver.

So i installed it but there is one thing bugging me 
when i open any html file it gets open but I also want its other linked files to be opened as well so it would be easier in finding those files and editing them.

can someone suggest me what that feature is called and "how to enable it in Aptana"

thank you for reading my story above :)

Comment: oh I just found an article explaining that feature its called "Related Files" and was introduced with Dreamweaver CS4. here is the link to article explaining this feature in more detail:http://www.computerrepairmaintenance.com/top-3-new-features-in-adobe-dreamweaver-cs4/
see point 2

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found it. That's not a current feature in Aptana, but you can file a feature request for it here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD